# Dragged HTML elements always follow the mouse loosely, is synchronous dragging with Javascript impossible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Notice: This question is only about plain Javascript and HTML.

I've tried the usual method to move HTML elements around with the mouse inside a mousemove event function like so:

```
element.style.left = e.clientX - offset.x + 'px';
element.style.top  = e.clientY - offset.y + 'px';
```

Earlier I had captured the x-y offset inside an element.mousedown function and zeroed it in a document mouseup function.

The problem is that the HTML element always follows the mouse loosely, like it is attached via a rubber band. This happens because Javascript updates the HTML element's position at least one or more frames later, which is annoying, and looks sloppy and poorly made.

To see this effect drag the object quickly horizontally from one edge of the screen to another on this codepen (that comes from another question). Then try moving a window on your PC to see the huge difference.

https://codepen.io/kosarh79/pen/wqXGdE

This is only **one** example, I've seen several, and all have the same problem. I've noticed that this issue is getting worse when there is a heavier element, like a form, since it takes more time to draw.

UPDATE:
Here is a screen capture of the issue -it is amplified quite a bit due to simultaneous recording, but you get the picture:

[image]

Comment: The codepen example works flawlessly for me, fwiw.

Comment: Not sure if either of these suit your purpose, but have you considered the [drag and drop api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) and/or [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)?

Comment: @ray hatfield I have updated the question with a screen capture. Obviously your PC is newer and powerful.
I have used requestAnimationFrame inside 3D frameworks like three.js but never in plain JS/HTML, I'll see what it can do tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: The cursor is not really painted by the browser's renderer, but more by the OS directly, it will thus not be blocked the same way as the page's content. The best you can do is probably to make your dragged element be rendered the fastest possible, [using `translate`](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/JjOGzxN) may help a bit in that matter as it should use the GPU to render your element. An other more hackish solution would be replace the cursor with an HTML element, there would still be some delay, but it won't be visible anymore since the "cursor" would also be late.

Comment: I tried both translate and window.requestAnimationFrame and the result was the same, which means that the page processing is always synched at least 1 frame later, so on a second thought this is impossible to solve, as the real cause is the crappy nature of Windows OS itself that is built upon an ancient architecture (not fast response optimized), and only a very powerful PC can minimize or eliminate today.
So the only workaround left is to use a fake mouse attached to the element while it is moving as Kaiido suggested, which I had thought too but I was looking for a real solution.

Comment: Do you have any CSS using the `transition` property? If so, make sure you're not using `all` or any of the positions `top|right|bottom|left`